# Constant margins in book class

Tags: margins, geometry

I use the book document class and I have margins set like this:

`\usepackage[top = 1.2cm, bottom = 1.2cm, left = 2cm, right = 1cm]{geometry}`

But the left and right margin switch depending on that is the page number even or odd. For example, on the page 1 the left margin is 2cm and the right margin is 1cm, on the page 2 the left margin is 1cm and the right margin is 2cm. How can I disable this, so that on the all pages the left margin is 2cm and the right margin is 1cm?

Comment: Use the `oneside` option for the document class (`\documentclass[oneside]{book}`).

Comment: Try to pass the option `oneside` to the book class, it should prevent this behaviour from happening.

Comment: But do you intend to print  one-sided?

Comment: @Bernard No, I don't. I just wanted to know how to do it. It may come in handy one day.

Comment: Thanks, @PhelypeOleinik, adding `oneside` option works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `oneside` option for the book class allows you to do what you want:

```
\documentclass[12pt, oneside]{book}
\usepackage[top = 1.2cm, bottom = 1.2cm, left = 2cm, right = 1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\chapter{1}
\blindtext[5]
\chapter{2}
\blindtext[5]
\chapter{3}
\blindtext[5]

\end{document}
```

Romain